# How are 4 bytes characters represented in C#

Tags: c#, .net, astral-plane

How are 4 bytes chars are represented in C#? Like one char or a set of 2 chars?

```
var someCharacter = 'x'; //put 4 bytes UTF-16 character
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a '4 bytes char'? It would make your question clearer.

Comment: @jv42, there are some UTF-16 characters which can not be represented by 2 bytes. So it is any character with code out of 2^16

Comment: See "Unicode and .NET" article by Jon Skeet - http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx

Comment: I know those chars exist, providing an example would have made certain there was not a typo in the question, especially as 'char' and 'character' meanings are sometimes confusing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C# can only store characters from the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) in the `char` type. For characters outside this plane two `char`s must be used - called [surrogates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Surrogates).

You can also use a string literal such as:

```
string s = "\U0001D11E";
```

See [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).